# Create a Bucket with HTML file from a Lambda (want HTML, get Octet Stream)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

Geez, I thought this would be easy, but I'm stuck. I created a bucket with the AWS SDK, created a file in that bucket which I want to be an HTML file. I get an HTML file, but S3 insists that it has to be an Octet-steam. What I want is for it to render in a browser.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Body: '<html>hi</html>',
    Metadata: {
        'Content-Type': 'Application/html'
    },
    ACL: 'public-read'
};
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
    }
});
```

Long story, but trying not to do it from the CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your Content-Type should be `text/html`, not `Application/html`.

Comment: I also found this after my post, it helped a lot: http://blog.katworksgames.com/2014/01/26/nodejs-deploying-files-to-aws-s3/

Comment: @MattHealy note also that the `Content-Type` header isn't sent as part of `Metadata`.  What's shown in the question would create `x-amz-meta-Content-Type`.  It needs to be a top-level key in `params`, named `ContentType`.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: Thx Matt... I don't know where I found that code for the metadata tag.